# Is it okay to double wrap 18650 cells?

Tags: lithium-ion, batteries, cell

I’ve got some salvaged 18650 cells here that I’m looking to sell. Most have perfectly intact wraps/sleeves, but some have small nicks showing bare metal that I’d like to fix. I want to rewrap these ones, but in doing so I’d be removing the original wrap with the manufacturer’s branding, which I think could hurt their value for high quality branded cells.

Are there any drawbacks to putting a new wrap on top of the existing wrap? I’m thinking about heat mainly, but maybe there are other considerations? I know the cells will be marginally bigger than usual. I intend to keep the ones I rewrap, I think.

Comment: Why do you care if removing the original wrap "could hurt their value" if you intend to keep the ones you rewrap? Just do it.

Comment: Apart from mechanical compatibility, I don’t see any reason why you couldn’t double wrap them.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fine, given that cells with a protection PCB require double wrapping in order to electrically insulate the nickel strips.

Here are a couple of photos from different suppliers of protection boards, to demonstrate:

[image]

[image]